# Function fread and ASCII files

Tags: r, ascii, fread

I am trying to do a loop to duplicate and rename an asci file several times. My loop works fine, but I am struggling with the 'fread' function when trying to import my ascii files in a first place.

My original ascii file looks like this:

[image]

And here is the code I have been using so far

```
library(purrr)
library(data.table)
files=list.files(pattern = "*.asc")
    fileDF<-files%>%map(fread, fill=TRUE, header="auto", sep="auto") 
    fileDF
```

Now fileDF looks like this

```
      V1            V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24 V25 V26 V27 V28 V29 V30 V31 V32 V33 V34 V35 V36 V37 V38 V39 V40 V41
 1:        ncols    41.0000000 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 2:        nrows    44.0000000 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 3:    xllcorner  -133.2624969 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 4:    yllcorner    41.3875008 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 5:     cellsize     0.2916667 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 6: NODATA_value -9999.0000000 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 7:          0.0     0.0000000  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 8:            0     0.0000000  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 9:            0     0.0000000  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
10:            0     0.0000000  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
11:            0     0.0000000  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
12:           10    10.0000000  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
13:           10    10.0000000 10  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
14:           10    10.0000000 10 10 10 10 10  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
15:           10    10.0000000 10 10 10 10 10  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Obviously, the new files I get after running the loop are different from my original one, and cannot be read in the other software I use (because different spatial format).

I tried to remove the NA with `na.string=NULL`, and to remove the automatic renaming of rows and columns with `colnames` but nothing seems to work. I am just trying to get the exact same format as my original ascii file.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is how to

> duplicate and rename a file several times.

You could do that like this

```
outf <- paste0("copy_", 1:10, ".asc") 
inf <- "test.asc"
for (i in 1:length(outf)) {
    file.copy(inf, outf[i])
}
```

Or with lapply

```
lapply(outf, \(f) file.copy(inf, f)
```

Comment: Let's say I have an ascii file which describes the spatial distribution of one species in january.I am trying to replicate this exact file for every january month of every year of my research. My loop code seems to do that fine. My problem is that those replicated files have some additional row/columns names, as well as some NA (in comparison to my original file). I believe the problem is in my fread function, as fileDF in my example already ends up with those additional columns/rows. Is that more clear? Thank you for your help!

Comment: if you want to replicate files you should use copy them, e.g. with `file.copy`. There should not read them.

Comment: I am managing to replicate the files. I think the problem is that when I extract those multiple files from my original folder with fread, the file get changed and columns, NA, and rows are added. Could it be because the rows of original files have different numbers of columns?

Comment: It makes no sense to use `fread`